# JSF/Primefaces: CommandButton Redirection

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I am using CommandButton with ajax="true". I need that the redirection should happen only from oncomplete method. Can anybody please help. Now it is directly redirecting instead of checking any thing in oncomplete.

```
<p:commandButton id="save"
 global="false" ajax="true"
 value="Submit"
 action="#{OrderBean.saveAndSubmit()}"
 oncomplete="RedirectionJS()"
/>
```

Comment: Try `oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) RedirectionJS()"`

Comment: @jasperdevries: I suspect OP already sends the redirect in the server-side method and wants to then prevent itt someway on the client-side. That will never work.

Comment: Did you try to make it work from the ManagedBean ?!?

Comment: I think what @kukeltje said is valid. There is no way to prevent from client side.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your Javascript and Java is supposed to do, this might work:

```
<p:commandButton
  id="save"
  global="false"
  value="Submit"
  action="#{OrderBean.saveAndSubmit()}"
  oncomplete="RedirectionJS(); {window.location.href='redirect.xhtml';}"
/>
```

You can omit the ajax attribute, because it is on true by default. You could also put the bit of JS with "{window.location.href='redirect.xhtml';}" into your RedirectionJS() after an if().